# Sending The Content of a Document Type Via UmbracoApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, umbraco, umbraco7

How Can i OutPut the published Content of a Certain Document Type via Web Api?

**Example:**
I have a Document Type Called

Comment

its has three Properties "Name, Date, Text"
I Want To output the Values of those Properties to a UmbracoApiController So that I can Use it in other WebSites
any thoughts ? Thanks in Advance

```
 public class  publishedContentapiController  : UmbracoApiController
{
    //What Logic To Put Here In Order to get the Content OF published 
   // Document Types With the Alias "comment" 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code outputs **all** documents of type "comment" through the webapi

```
public class  publishedContentapiController  : UmbracoApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetComments()
    {
        // Create an UmbracoHelper for retrieving published content
        var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);

        // Get all comments from the Umbraco tree (this is not a optimized way of doing this, since it queries the complete Umbraco tree)
        var comments = umbracoHelper.TypedContentAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf("comment");     

        // Map the found nodes from IPublishedContent to a strongly typed object of type Comment (defined below)
        var mappedComments = comments.Select(x => new Comment{
            Name = x.Name,                              // Map name of the document
            Date = x.CreatedTime,                       // Map createdtime
            Text = x.GetPropertyValue<string>("text")   // Map custom property "text"
        });

        return Ok(mappedComments);
    }


    private class Comment
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Diclaimer: Code is untested and obviously needs refactoring

Comment: Dose It Send it as json ? 
i dont know what the IHttpActionResult is actuality

Comment: it's send as json or xml depending on your accept headers, you can also replace `IHttpActionResult` with `IEnumerable<Comment>` and do `return mappedComments;` instead of `return Ok(mappedComments);`

Comment: Just a fast question if i added a new property to the Document Type 
Now i need to recompile And Add New Item to the Class 
How Can i make it Send the whole think even if they added some new proprieties ?

Comment: I added the Comment viewmodel to take control over the data you expose through the webapi (for both security and performance). This is normally a good way to go.

If you want to expose all the properties all the time (which I don't recommend personally), you can consider returning the IPublishedContent (that are in the `comments` collection) objects or use modelsbuilder. Modelsbuilder creates strongly typed models from you umbraco nodes. It has a bit of a learning curve though, you can check it out here: https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2016/getting-started-with-modelsbuilder/